# Paused Activity

Tags: android

This is the definition of paused activity in android: Another activity is visible on top of this one and that activity is partially transparent or doesn't cover the entire screen.

But i can't see an activity that partially transparent this activity. I don't know when an activity partially transparent paused activity.  Can every one show an image of paused activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine another activity that uses a transparent background or a dialog theme. If such an activity is above your activity, then your activity is still visible (at least partially). And in this case your activity will be paused.

Comment: Thanks i use dialog them for my test activity but i can't use any other app bellow this activity! in emulator.  
I can't run two app in android emulator!

Comment: You can't, but the OS can. E.g. while user sees your activity (works with it) some event happens and OS starts another app whose activity has a transparent background.